# query to app engine database coming up blank

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

i have this issue with app engine's datastore. In interactive console, I always get no entities when i ask if a url already exists in my db. When I execute the following code....

```
from google.appengine.ext import db    
class shortURL(db.Model):
    url = db.TextProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
q = shortURL.all()
#q.filter("url =", "httphello")
print q.count()
for item in q:
    print item.url
```

i get the this response, which is fine

```
6
httphello 
www.boston.com
http://www.boston.com 
httphello
www.boston.com 
http://www.boston.com
```

But when I uncomment the line "q.filter("url =", "httphello")", i get no entities at all (a response of 0). I know its something ultra simple, but I just can't see it! help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TextProperty](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty) values are not indexed, and cannot be used in filters or sort orders.
You might want to try with [StringProperty](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringProperty) if you don't need more than 500 characters.

Comment: yeah, that pretty much did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think .fetch() is missing . you can do a fetch before you do some manipulation on a model.

Also. I don't think you need db.TextProperty() for this, you can use db.StringProperty().